# Flutter web, recording session with smartlook or hotjar showing blanck screen

Tags: flutter, web, analytics, recording

I've created a web langing page using flutter, the page is shown on browser as expected.
Inside the html code, i've added the scripts to integrate screen recording with hotjar and smartlook.

In the smrtlook and the hotjar consoles, i can see the recording of the sessions but, these are complete blank.
All the records are white screens, whith only the tap/click/swipe gestures.

I've added inside the  tag in the app html this line

as described (by smartlook) [here](https://web.developer.smartlook.com/docs/canvas) without solving my problem.

Do i placed this tag in the wrong position?
Does the app needs to be built with renderer canvaskit rather than html?
Is there something else i'm not considering?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something working by building my web app using --web-renderer html:

[image]

You'll notice though that the text is odd in the recording (e.g. it all shows up as asteriks)

When I did not specify the [web renderer](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers#command-line-options), the recording showed the mouse movement and clicks but the background was completely blank.